# Как я могу прогрузить карту в кэш и загрузить этот кэш на другую машину ? (QML Map)

Tags: qt, qt5, qml

Вопрос по части кэширование данных карты QML. Когда я скроллю карту - она прогружается в кэш. Возникает вопрос, как я могу сохранить этот кэш и залить на другую машину где нет интернета? (По простому говоря - как на машине где нет интернета подгрузить кэш из папки?)

```
 Map {
    id: map
    z: 0.1
    objectName: "map"
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: Plugin { name: "itemsoverlay" }
}
```